# Total number of combinations with exclusions

Tags: combinatorics

I never made it out of grade $8$ math and I feel silly asking something that seems so basic so please bear with me.

I want to calculate the total number of possible combinations of a set of numbers where:

The numbers cannot repeat. 
They must be in ascending order. 
They can not be in direct ascending order more than $3$ times in any group. 
They must be in groups of $7$.

So for example $1234567$ is invalid, but so is $124568$ because $1$,$2$ and $4$,$5$,$6$ are all direct ascending order.

I'm not really looking for any specific set of numbers but if it helps, lets use numbers from $1$ - $100$.

Comment: Direct ascending order = consecutive?

Comment: Yes, consecutive, but not odd or even consecutive. 2 4 6 or 1 3 5 would be valid.

Comment: This is not trivial. What's the motivation for this problem?

Comment: Because I have to know. I have quite a severe case of ADHD and it causes me to become hyperfocused on specific details sometimes. Today I woke up and my brain decided to focus on Math. I don't know why, but I found myself with this question in my head and now I can't get it out.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand what it means to be consecutive 3 times. Your example is puzzling. $12$ $456$ is only two groups of consecutive numbers. $456$ is a group of three consecutive numbers, which by some interpretations is invalid, but that doesn't seem to be what you mean because otherwise there's no need to mention the $12$.

Comment: Perhaps you mean the pairs 12 45 56.

Comment: 123 is a group of three consecutive numbers. That would be the total number of consecutive numbers allowed in any group. Adding a 4 (1234) would invalidate it because it would be one more consecutive number but ALSO adding 56 (12356) would invalidate because 5 and 6 are consecutive numbers. 

Sorry again, this is as difficult for me to explain as it probably is for you to understand.